# sed replace unix path with variable that contain another unix path

Tags: unix, path, sed, replace, var

I need to replace Unix path via sed with variable that contain another unix path in a bash script

Example:

```
another_unix_path=/another/unix/path
sed -i 's/ \/some\/path\/file.txt/ '$another_unix_path'/g' some_file.txt
```

Comment: What work have you done on this so far? Please provide examples you've tried, and how they didn't end up working for you.

Comment: Duplicate of [Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to escape special characters:

```
another_unix_path="\/another\/unix\/path"
echo /some/path/file.txt | sed -e 's/\/some\/path\/file.txt/'$another_unix_path'/g'
```

Which outputs this result:

> /another/unix/path

Answer (score 3):

Escaping special char `/` is an option.

You can also change the default `sed` separator (which is `/`) by using `?` for example :

```
another_unix_path="/another/unix/path"
echo /some/path/file.txt | sed -e 's?/some/path/file.txt?'$another_unix_path'?g'
```

The char used just after the `s` flag defines which separator will be used : `s?`

**Edit :**

```
#!/bin/sh
basepath=/another/unix/path
baseurl=/base/url
sed -i 's?# set $IMAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;? set $IMAGE_ROOT '$basepath$baseurl';?g' somefile.txt
```

Comment: @user289782 See my edit

Answer (score 1):

If you use `/` for separators, then you'll have to escape every `/` in your path, ex `sed 's/\/some\/path/'$replacement'/g'`

Fortunately sed - like Perl - allows many characters to be used as separators, so you can also write `sed 's#/some/path#'$replacement'#g'` (the `g` flag is used to allow replacing multiple occurrences per line).

<s>Also sed will not allow in-place replacement if you run it on a file, meaning you will have to write to a temp file and move it over.</s> **Update:** actually, Gnu's sed **does** have an in-place option which work like Perl's: `-i` or `-i.ext` where `.ext` is the backup extension. Perl may be preferable for portability though.

For in-place replacement you can use Perl as such:

```
# In-place without backup:
perl -pi -e 's#/some/path#'$replacement'#g' <file>

# In-place with backup as .orig (note .orig is glued to the -i switch):
perl -pi.orig -e 's#/some/path#'$replacement'#g' <file>
```

Be careful with the 2nd command, as if you enter it twice you will overwrite your first backup!